# Can't boot XP only Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

I have used Windows XP for years.  I partitioned my HD with 300 GB for XP and 1 TB for Ubuntu.  I installed v.14.04 successfully.  When booting I get a menu choice defaulting to Ubuntu and then XP.  Selecting XP only brings me back to the boot menu.  Can the XP boot be repaired.  As it is I can only get to my XP data through Ubuntu.  I would like to have a choice that works.  I could not install Ubuntu along side XP because the only given choice was another HD not the partition.

---

**Update**

I ran boot-repair and TestDisk trying to repair bootup. Now I get `grub recovery>` and running my installation disk for Ubuntu gets to the Ubuntu window with the five moving dots and locks up. I have no idea what commands to use with `grub recovery>` and I can't get to a terminal without Ubuntu running.

I did try to recover Windows XP boot without reloading XP thinking it might repair the BIOS. I also ran `chkdsk /R`. None of this helped; I got the same result.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu, now neither will boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058806/tried-to-install-both-windows-and-ubuntu-now-neither-will-boot)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore XP by performing a "Chkdsk -f" from a Windows command prompt. Now of coarse since you are unable to open XP itself, you will need to get to the cp using a Windows installation disk, or a boot disk like Active@ Boot Disk by lsoft. Unfortunately you cannot perform a Chkdsk from Linux.

Comment: This will remove Grub and prevent booting into Ubuntu. And you can perform chkdsk from linux; run the command fsck.ntfs /dev/<windows partition>

Answer (score 0):

Probably something wrong with GRUB.

Try re-installing your bootloader (GRUB).

Run the following in your terminal on Ubuntu:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```