# How can I repair my Boot Manager?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-order

I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad u330p. It came with Windows 10 preinstalled.

I installed Ubuntu 16.4 on a separate partition and the default boot loader was replaced with Grub 2.

I have since uninstalled Ubuntu but found I was unable to boot from a UEFI USB or CD/DVD device through Grub.

I uninstalled Grub hoping it would default to the Windows Boot Loader. This wasn't the case. I now receive the following error message;

"System boot order not found. Initializing defaults"

The system then resets and gets stuck in a loop with this error message.

If I load the boot order menu using the Novo button I am able to launch windows. However changing the boot order in the bios does not persist when I exit, as such I am still unable to use the windows boot manager to install anything.

Further more, I am unable to access the partition that Ubuntu was installed on.

It cannot be seen or accessed from within Windows.

Can anybody tell me how to;

a) Wipe the hard drive completely and reinstall an operating system?
b) Repair the boot loader?
c) Access the partition that Ubuntu was installed on? (It is on an LVM partition)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu, now neither will boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058806/) and [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to format and reinstall, but you might be able to use Hirens Boot disk to repair the MBR.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are:

Boot from the original installation DVD (or the bootable USB)

At the Welcome screen, click Repair your computer >
    Choose Troubleshoot >
    Choose Command Prompt
When the Command Prompt loads, type the following commands:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

Windows 10 Repair Your Computer Menu

Press Enter after each command and wait for each operation to finish

Remove the DVD from the disk tray

```
Type exit
Hit Enter
```

Restart your computer and check if Windows 8/8.1/10 can now boot.

Here is a [link](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/) you can look for further help.