# WIndows boot loader not appearing in bios boot order after upgrading to ubuntu 19.04

Tags: grub2, bios, boot-repair

I was dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 before. Now after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 , my laptop directly boots into ubuntu without grub menu. Also when I checked the bios boot menu there was no windows boot loader. I ran boot-repair by booting into live usb and this is the link it gave me http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4k8Qx3x7TV/.

I dont think the EFI System is mounted on /boot/efi. In fact I dont even have such a mount point. Could that be the cause of this problem? Any help appreciated.

Edit - This is not a duplicate as in my situation I am unable to locate the windows boot loader in the BIOS

Comment: @physicas123 _Lilo is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda._ Why were you using lilo?

Comment: @K7AAY I read in some other answer that maybe it could fix the problem....

Comment: Report is not showing any /EFI/Microsoft EFI boot files. And no entry in UEFI. You probably need your Windows repair disk and run a full set of repairs to reinstall its UEFI boot loader. Be sure to only boot in UEFI boot mode since system is UEFI, and installs are UEFI. If you boot in BIOS mode, it may try to repair in BIOS mode and that can further damage system.

Comment: @oldfred at line 32 "Boot files: /Windows/System32/winload.exe"..isn't this the windows boot loader?

Comment: Its one of three. And that one is in the main partition. The others with UEFI boot are in the /EFI/Microsoft folder in the ESP. /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi l& /efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/BCD Will now repair Windows BIOS & UEFI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058806/tried-to-install-both-windows-and-ubuntu-now-neither-will-boot

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I understand that you feel that this question is not a duplicate, but after reviewing the information in your question, as of this moment I have to ask did you attempt [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/921722/225694)?

Answer (score 1):

See line 830:

```
=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled. (maybe sec-boot, Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com)
```

So please report above message and get back to us with their reply.

It's been reported a bug in Grub 2.04 utilizes secure boot by default and downgrading to 2.02 fixes the problem:

- [Grub EFI amd64 no longer start EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1845289)

Comment: I haven't tried downgrading yet but will doing this bring back windows boot loader option back in the BIOS options ?

Comment: Best thing to do is email to boot repair people include link to this Q&A so they can read everything here and reply to you.