# MBR repair tool

Tags: mbr

I have a dual-boot configuration with Windows 8.1 and Kubuntu. Apparently Windows did some changes and now I can't boot Kubuntu anymore. I started Kubuntu from the usb disk, but I didn't find any tools there I could use. I've tried several of the Ubuntu tools, Boot Repair, etc. They didn't work. One of them messed up the MBR so Windows wouldn't start either. Windows had to run the system recovery tool and perform a lengthy check and repair of the C partition before it could start. So now I'm back to square one. Help, anybody?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu, now neither will boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058806/tried-to-install-both-windows-and-ubuntu-now-neither-will-boot)

Comment: Windows 8 pre-installed is UEFI, so MBR is not used for booting. If you install a boot loader to MBR, that would create issues. Post link from Summary Report that Boot-Repair creates.