# Tried to Dual Boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I was originally trying to install Ubuntu on a USB drive, but then I decided just to dual-boot it. Ubuntu told me to disable Intel RST, so I followed the steps [in this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/) until I got to the commands.

Basically, none of the commands work other than listing volumes and selecting volumes. It doesn't detect the `C:\` drive as a Windows boot drive. At this point in time, I have no installation of Ubuntu and an unbootable Windows installation.

Please help. I don’t want to lose my Windows installation, even if I have a backup. What steps should I take next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu, now neither will boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058806/tried-to-install-both-windows-and-ubuntu-now-neither-will-boot)

Comment: Mind elaborating a bit? Please [edit] your question to include exact error messages, as well as exactly what commands you ran. Also, if Ubuntu isn’t installed, and you want to fix Windows, you probably need a Windows repair/recovery drive. Or, you might be able to repair Windows by booting to Windows recovery. Fixing Windows is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu, but we might be able to hel you get Ubuntu setup

Comment: You need to follow through with the Ubuntu installation. Once Ubuntu is installed, there is a 'trick' you can use that will result in ubuntu installing the Windows Boot option. It is not the C drive that Windows boots from. That said, trying to set it up yourself, as it sounds like you are doing, is not the best option. Get Ubuntu running, and windows will be 1 command away.

Comment: @NateT what would the command be to get Windows?

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-image-5.11.0-N-generic` where `N` is any distribution of the kernel that you do not already have. Preferably a newer version, but older works as well. The newest is automatically loaded when you boot. What you need is just the installation process, not the kernel. As part of the process, apt digs around the boot drive for additional kernel versions. If the windows boot option is missing, apt will find it and automatically put back the boot menu entry. You can find out your version, once installed, with the command `uname -a`

Comment: I did the same thing on my first installation. Went a couple months thinking it was just gone, until i upgraded with apt. Then it was magically back. Ive intentionally unset it since then just to test. It works every time.

Comment: @"Nate T"  (Do not use spaces in Linux  world.) Any update to kernel or grub reruns the grub-update which runs os-prober. If system is correctly configured as both UEFI and Windows is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk then all you need is `sudo update-grub`. But Windows fast start up must be off & Windows turns it back on with updates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation