# I tried to install Ubuntu and it broke

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, grubrescue, data-corruption

I tried installing Ubuntu with Windows for a dual boot. I installed Ubuntu on a seperate hard drive but it somehow replaced the windows boot loader and grub corrupted after it did.

Comment: Please let us know what windows and what ubuntu version you tried to install. Would be also nice to know what you first installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu, now neither will boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058806/tried-to-install-both-windows-and-ubuntu-now-neither-will-boot) If you can still boot into either of the two OSs in the dual boot please comment and share this information.